# How to compare a string with symbol '\'

Tags: c, string, char, compare, strcmp

I have a project and somewhere in my code I'm writing this:

```
else if (character[0] == '\'){
```

How can I compare my character with this symbol? Every other symbol that I tried to compare like `,`, `;`, etc. is done and this is the only symbol that I'm getting a wrong message.

Comment: `'\\'` or `'/'`? And *how* are you comparing the characters?

Comment: sorry i edit my question. i mean '\'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backslash `\` is used as an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), so you would need to write:

```
else if (character[0] == '\\'){
```

In this case the backslash is being used to escape itself.

Comment: in my program im getting char by char the code and im trying to find if we have comment. So i want to find \* because in my language comments are inside this \*.....*\. So i want firstly to find \ then * etc but i cant.

Comment: How does this relate to the original question ? If you have a new question then please post it as such.

Comment: im telling you this because when im going to compare my character with '\' im getting wrong message but now that i used the ascii code 92 i think is true

Comment: Why aren't you just using `'\\'` as described above ? That would be a better solution then using the ASCII code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear on what you ask. Do you mean to compare like this:

```
if (character[0] == '\\') {
```

or you could do

```
if (character[0] == 92) { // ASCII-Code
```

Comment: in my program im getting char by char the code and im trying to find if we have comment. So i want to find \* because in my language comments are inside this \*.....*\. So i want firstly to find \ then * etc but i cant.